# Eclipse Export Android apk hanging

Tags: android, export, apk, keystore

I have a problem that when exporting an APK with Eclipse it just hangs and doesn't complete. When I shut down Windows I see an error message saying "Enter keystore password:" but without offering an input box. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was that the keystore password I was entering contained these characters: $ £ % ! "

I'm not sure which character caused the problem, but after choosing a password that didn't contain any of these characters, the problem stopped occurring.