# Is the Android Eclipse Export APK freeze caused by Windows 7 file locking?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just read the folowing URL,
        [Eclipse Export Android apk hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521015/eclipse-export-android-apk-hanging)
    It says to change  the keystore password which I disagree with since my keystore password is all letters and numbers.
    I am curious whether this problem is caused by Windows 7 file locking. If so, please tell me how to fix this. I already have rebooted and restarted Eclipse to no avail.
    Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this freeze by creating a new Android Virtual Device and then launching my Android APK again with Debug in concert with a  new Debug  Configuration using  my new Android Virtual Device.
  Also, I suggest creating a new Android Appliocatiob Project and copying your code over.
  Thank you.